# As user calls APIs, build array of observables, and execute block when all resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to build a list of observables as a user interacts with the page. Each observable is individually subscribed, but I would like another function to be called after individual or multiple concurrent API calls are made.

I have each function pushing an observable to an array, and I have a forkJoin and subscription to the array in my ngOnInit, but this fires only once. How can I make a live subscription that will do a callback function once all current API calls return and continue to do so as the user continues to make API calls?

For example, the user clicks "Create Thing," then does nothing.

```
forkJoin(thingsInProgress).subscribe(() => doStuffWhenAllResolve())

...

createThing() {
    const = this.thingService.createThing().pipe(tap(() => doStuff()));
    thingsInProgress.push(createThing$);
    createThing$.subscribe();
}

deleteThing() {
    ...
}

updateThing() {
    ...
}
```

I want `doStuff()` to fire, then `doStuffWhenAllResolve()` to fire. Or, if user clicks "Create Thing", "Delete Thing", "Update Thing" all within milliseconds of each other, `doStuff()` (for example) is called once for each, and `doStuffWhenAllResolve()` is called once for all.

Then, if the user creates 10 more things really quickly, `doStuffWhenAllResolve()` is called once more after all overlapping API calls return.

What RXJS operator am I looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a `BehaviorSubject` where `createThing()`, `deleteThing()`, and `updateThing()` each emit and couple it with a `debounceTime`.

Something like this:

```
actionMade$ = new BehaviourSubject(new Date());

this.actionMade$.pipe(
  debounceTime(100), // Up to you to play with this 100, basically how long in ms does it have 
                     // to wait before accepting a new actionMade$
  switchMap(() => forkJoin(thingsInProgress)),
).subscribe(() => doStuffWhenAllResolve());

createThing() {
  ...
  this.actionMade$.next(new Date());
}

deleteThing() {
  ...
  this.actionMade$.next(new Date());
}

updateThing() {
  ...
  this.actionMade$.next(new Date());
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.actionMade$.complete();
}
```

====================================================
Be sure to unsubscribe from your subscriptions (using sub.unsubscribe or takeUntil) or else they can make a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me see if I understand.
So, I am creating an observable of date, and waiting 100 milliseconds after each .next() to see if a new .next() comes in? When the time elapses, the subscription will trigger?
If that's the case, what is the function of the switchMap? Do I still need an array of observables at that point?

Comment: Basically the debounceTime waits 100ms in between successions of `actionMade$`. So if a user clicks `deleteThing` then after `50ms`, clicks on `updateThing`, then nothing, the emission from `deleteThing` is ignored and the emission of `updateThing` is accepted.
SwitchMap switches to a different observable (think of it as shifting gear to somewhere else). This way `actionMade$` becomes the main listener, okay we go an actionMade$ => switch to the forkJoin of this array (this way the forkJoin will always be fresh).